# Failed to send post request with Capacitor (works fine from regular webpage)

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, axios, capacitor

I'm working on an app using Ionic (Vue) and have already set a server side (Python with FastAPI).

While I've no issues sending a request when running my app on the browser (`ionic serve`), I fail to do so when running it on iOS simulator.

I've tried both `axios` and Capacitor HTTP library and the outcomes are the same.
Below are only the relevant parts from client:

```
<template>
<base-layout page-title="Choose Players" page-default-back-link="/home">
  <ion-item v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.phoneNumbers[0]" @click="toggleContact(contact)">
    <ion-icon v-if="isContactSelected(contact)" slot="end" :icon="checkmark"/>
    {{ contact.displayName }}
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button expand="block" @click="inviteSelectedContacts">Invite Selected Contacts</ion-button>
</base-layout>
</template>

<script>
import { IonItem, IonIcon, IonButton } from "@ionic/vue";
import { checkmark } from 'ionicons/icons';
import { Contacts } from "@capacitor-community/contacts";
import { serverURL } from '@/components/Config';
// import axios from 'axios';
import { Http } from '@capacitor-community/http';


export default {
  name: "AddPlayers",

  

  data() {
    return {
      contacts: [],
      chosenContacts: new Set()
    };
  },

  methods: {
    
    async inviteSelectedContacts() {
      let data = {userId: 'test id', users: this.chosenContacts}
      let url = `${serverURL}/inviteUsers`;
      try {
        let options = {url: url, data: data}
        let res = await Http.post(options);
        if (res.status === 200){
          alert(res.status)
        }
        return res.data
      }
      catch (err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    }
  },
```

My conclusion is that it's somehow related to CORS not being defined properly for Capacitor **only** (as they're working just fine for the browser), but I couldn't understand where should I define those.

The server API url is `http://fastapi.localhost:8008`

**Update:**
I was able to log and view the error (via `Xcode`):

```
[log] - {"message":"Network Error","name":"Error","stack":"createError@\nhandleError@","config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json"},"method":"post","url":"http://fastapi.localhost:8008/inviteUsers","data":"{\"userId\":\"test id\",\"users\":{}}"},"status":null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much time wasted on this one...

It turns out that the solution was to change the development server URL to an IP based one: `http://127.0.0.1:8008` (in my case).

I don't know why Capacitor doesn't accept DNS naming.

I was able to verify it by adding this dummy endpoint to my server:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
...
@app.post("/dummypath")
async def get_body(request: Request):
    return await request.json()
```

so now from the client:

```
async inviteSelectedContacts() {
  // let data = {userId: 'test id', users: this.chosenContacts}
  let data = {}
  let url = `${serverURL}/dummypath`;
  try {
    let res = await axios.post(url, data);
    if (res.status === 200){
      alert(res.status)
    }
    alert(res);
    return res.data
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    alert(err);
  }
}
```

where `serverURL` is `http://127.0.0.1:8008`